# Python calculations without scientific notation

Tags: python, math, long-integer, scientific-notation

I have tried to use python to work with some big numbers, which hard to calculate manually. Let's say I have 2 in power of 256 as a long integer as a starting point. Then, when I want to do anything with it like divide by 2, python gives me value with scientific notation like this `5.78960446186581e+76`.

However, I need very precise numbers where everything makes a difference. How can I get rid of this scientific notation, when I'm doing calculations?

Comment: Do you use python 2.7 or 3.x?

Comment: You don't get more precision by not using scientific notation. You get the same 53 bits of precision no matter what; that's how floats work. Scientific notation is just a matter of how those floats are displayed, not what's in them. You can do, e.g., `format(mynum, 'f')` and see all the digits—but most of them are meaningless noise.

Comment: Your question is a bit odd, because those numbers are the same number regardless of if they have the scientific notation.  Are you asking about printing them?  Or is this just a question about increasing accuracy of floating point arithmetic?

Comment: python 3 (3.6 I think)

Comment: Meanwhile, if you know how to trace errors and precision, you can use `decimal.Decimal` to do floating point with exactly the number of digits you want. It's a bit more complicated, and significantly slower, but it works.

Comment: Finally, depending on what math you're doing on these numbers, you may want to use `fractions.Fraction`, which can handle huge numbers exactly. Of course it stops being exact if you do something like `n**0.5`, and it can get very slow if you start using huge denominators, but it may be what you want here. It's hard to say unless you give us more information.

Comment: As I know if I would add 5 to the 5.78960446186581e+76 nothing would be changed, or thet's only the displayed numbers and the calculations are precise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the integer division in Python 3, e. g.:

```
a = 2 ** 256
print(a / 2)
print(a // 2)
```

This will print

```
5.78960446186581e+76
57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819968
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, I think it is what I searched for

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/decimal.html) module from the standard library:

```
import decimal

if __name__ == '__main__':
    decimal.getcontext().prec = 100
    a = decimal.Decimal(1) / decimal.Decimal(7)
    b = decimal.Decimal(str(a * decimal.Decimal(str(1e100))))
    print(a)
    print(b)
```

#### output:

`0.1428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571429
1428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571429`